# Some of the keys on my keyboard are not working

Tags: keyboard, temperature

Some of the keys on my keyboard are not working all of a sudden. I have a 2013 macbook pro. Some keys like the 'o' key work if I hold them down long enough, and some like 'e' don't work at all. This change occurred all of a sudden. I've tried resetting my computer several times, but to no avail. Any suggestions are appreciated. Hopefully my keyboard isn't just dead :(

Update:
Without further input of my own, the problem has apparently resolved itself. The one physical change that may hint towards the underlying problem is that my laptop has cooled significantly since I made this post originally.

Comment: RE: "I've tried resetting my computer several times" -- Without some context it means absolutely nothing! Do you have an external USB keyboard you can plug in, and if yes, does it work correctly when the internal one does not? Also, what version of **macOS** are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just dead.  I suggest plugging in an external keyboard to test if it's software or hardware.  If on the external keyboard the same keys don't work, then you know it is a software issue.  Otherwise if the external keyboard works fine, it's a hardware issue.

You can also take it to an Apple Store to get it diagnosed, and if it is broken, fixed.

Comment: I think I would have agreed that it's dead. However, in the time between posting and reading your comment, my keyboard is working again, even though I have seemingly done nothing to it. That said, the one physical change between then and now is that my laptop has cooled significantly. I wonder whether heat is causing a circuit to come disconnected as the components expand.

Comment: That's great!  Weird though.  I have found out computers sometimes, for some reason, fix themselves if you give them enough time.  Although it probably will break again soon, so you should only see it as a temporary fix.